# Android displaying online music playlist

Tags: android, audio

My android application has two activity one contains text quotes another will contain audio quotes.

The text quotes are on SQL server which syncs with the mobile device whenever the user clicks on sync.

I have used Webservice and SQL server database for the same and displaying the result in ListView. It is working fine.

Now, I want to create a similar activity for audio quotes. The difference being I don't want the audio files to be stored locally. I have never worked on audio files sync.

- Where should I upload the files?  Can I use free service like dropbox?
- How should I inform the user that the new audio file is uploaded?
- Is there a library or service available which I can use to achieve this in a short period of time?

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I upload the files? Can I use free service like dropbox?

You can look at [Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html). Amazon S3 has a simple web services interface that you can use to store and retrieve any amount of data, at any time, from anywhere on the web. Plus I the first is free with limits which should be enough to try out most trivial use cases.

> How should I inform the user that the new audio file is uploaded?

You can use [Amazon SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html). With Amazon SNS, you have the ability to send push notification messages directly to apps on mobile devices. Push notification messages sent to a mobile endpoint can appear in the mobile app as message alerts, badge updates, or even sound alerts.

> Is there a library or service available which I can use to achieve this in a short period of time?

The documentation at the given links are adequate for getting started in a short amount of time. And since you're familiar with using WebServices, interacting with Amazon API's shouldn't be difficult. You can the [AWS Mobile SDK for Android](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/) to get it up and running in a jiffy.

Comment: Any tutorial available? As the requirement looks common? Seen it on multiple apps.

Comment: Can I use IIS SERVER to store mp3 files and save url in database to achieve this?